# How would a stationary observer perceive an object moving near the speed of light on a closed loop?

Tags: special-relativity, observers

Suppose I'm standing in the middle of a circular train track, with a train going around the track near light speed, to me, would the train appear stationary at one point on the track? Would it appear to be everywhere at once? Is there another option?

(In this scenario the physics of the train, tracks, etc. being destroyed by even attempting such a feat is irrelevant, I'm just curious as to how it would visually appear.)

Comment: The train would just appear to be going round the track at near light speed. Why would it be any different? We do basically this in colliders like the large hadron collider where we send protons round in a circle at nearly the speed of light.

Comment: *how it would visually appear* As a blur, because the human visual system can’t process too-rapid changes. How your eyes process the scene is not a question about physics.

Comment: Let me first clarify, I'm a writer not a scientist. I would think the difference would be the train is solid matter as opposed to just some particles. Also I would think that the human eye would have a hard time perceiving something moving at that speed accurately when you can see all points on the track at once. I would think that the time it would take for the train to complete a rotation might be faster than the speed the eye can physically process, thus it might appear at all points on the track at once.

Comment: Yes, but that isn’t physics. The train is not actually everywhere at once. We just have a slow visual system.

Comment: @Ghoster thank you, that is what I suspected, but I also recognized the possibility of it not being visible at all, or possibly it just appearing as it was before it started, supposing it's acceleration was as near instantaneous as possible.

Comment: @Ghoster Who has more knowledge of objects moving at light speed than physicists? Just wanted to ask an expert

Comment: No one, although a train can’t move *at* light speed. There would be various physical effects that are independent of the human visual system. For example, the train would be Lorentz-contracted. And I think all the light from the train would get beamed very strongly in the forward direction of the train, like synchroton radiation, and be strongly blueshifted, so you wouldn’t actually “see” it but you would get fried if the train were ever coming toward you.

Comment: @Ghoster Wow that's fascinating! I'm familiar with length contraction, so with the blueshift,, would it just be like a blue blur everywhere on the track? Would it appear solid? or just like a mist of motion blur?

Comment: If the train were close enough to the speed of light, the “blue”shift could turn the light into gamma rays.

Comment: @Ghoster for the purposes of what I'm writing, the radiation is irrelevant at the moment. Like I said I'm just trying to wrap my head around what a human would visually see looking at something like that.

Comment: FWIW, if the track diameter is 1 km, and the train is going at 0.96c, it does almost 91,610 loops per second.

Comment: Of course, if the loop was large enough (and you could resolve the train at such a distance), then the angular speed of the train would be low enough that it wouldn't blur out as described above.  From @PM2Ring's numbers, just use a loop with a diameter of 100,000 km rather than 1 km.  (Constructing such a loop is an engineering problem and therefore off-topic for this stack.)  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We *know* what the train would look like because we have a practical experiment - the [Large Hadron Collider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider). Although this has bunches of protons instead of a train and a vacuum tube surrounded by superconducting magnets instead of a track, the principle is the same. The bunches of protons travel at $99.999999 \%$ of the speed of light and travel around the LHC ring over $11,000$ times per second. Of course, if you could *see* the protons you would just see a continuous blur because of the limitations of human vision. But very accurate measurements have confirmed that the proton bunches definitely still exist as discrete bunches and each bunch is contracted along the direction it is moving in accordance with Einstein's theories (indeed, if Einstein's theories were not correct to a very high degree of precision, the LHC would not work at all).